# If $f(x+y)-f(x-y)=4xy$, then is $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$?

Tags: functional-equations

As in the title. It may be very simple, but I'm having difficulty finding the proper substitution.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to solve it, just note that if $f_1(x)$ is some solution, then so is $f_1(x) + c$ for any $c \in \Bbb R$. Thus we have proven
$$
\text{There are solutions }\implies\text{ There are solutions with }f(0) \neq 0,1
$$
which is all we really need.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=x=z/2$ you obtain $f(z)=z^2$

Comment: Don't you get $f(z)-f(0) = z^2$? The question is actually about what $f(0)$ is. In fact $f(x) = x^2 +c$ is a solution for any $c\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: But what's the value of f(0) in our case?

Comment: @hetajr There is not enough information to tell. If we are only given that $f(x+y)-f(x-y) = 4xy$ then $f(0)$ can be any number. See Arthur's answer as well.

Comment: This answer seems to implicitly assume that $f(0)=0$. The reasoning seems circular.